# Django + Ajax: why does it redirect to a new URL and renders the response on browser?

Tags: javascript, django, ajax

Based on my understanding, ajax could be used to prevent the page from reloading/refreshing/redirecting after submitting a request to the server. However, my code will redirect to display the JSON response. I used e.preventDefault() and it didn't work. Is there anything that I am doing wrong?

My Django code looks like this:
views.py:

```
def projects(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        task_id = request.POST.get('task_id')
        myUser = User.objects.get(pk=request.user.id)
        myTask = Task.objects.get(pk = task_id)
        myTask.claimed.add(myUser) #add the user to the task
        return JsonResponse({'status': 'ok'})

    projects = Project.objects.all()
    tasks = Task.objects.all()
    open_tasks = tasks.filter(status='Created')
    proj_dict = {}
    context = {
        'projects' : projects,
        'tasks' : tasks,
        'open_tasks' : open_tasks,
    }
    return render(request, 'projects/projects.html', context)
```

My HTML:

```
<form action="{% url 'projects:' %}" method="POST" class='join-form' id='{{task.id}}'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" name="task_id" value={{task.id}}>
    <button type="submit" class=" claim-font claim-button">
        Join
    </button>
</form>
```

Tha ajax call:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#join-form').on('submit', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            const url = $(this).attr('action');
            console.log("here we are");
            const task_id = $(this).attr('id');
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: "json",
                headers: { 'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken },
                url: url,
                data: {
                    csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}',
                    task_id: task_id,
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    alert(data);
                    console.log("here we are");
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    console.log('error', response);
                    alert("shit")
                }
            })
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Seems like ajax will make sure that my browser doesn't redirect/reload/refresh after the submit button is clicked, and only the server-side changes. However, my browser turns out to be displaying: {"status": "ok"}

Any insights are greatly appreciated!

Comment: try removing the method and action form attributes, this should stop redirecting you

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you have class attribute for your form. Change your JQuery selector from `$('#join-form')` to `$('.join-form')` for class attributes

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.join-form').submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
          // write your code here
         });
        
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change button type from "submit" to "button"